# Developing a minesweeper game -Issues with my main function

Tags: c

I am currently trying to Code a minesweeper game for a project in C;
I am given very specific functions i need to implement and conditions to be met
I am still pretty new to c and have trouble identifying why things i believe should work, don't;

My issue occurs when trying to call to my function that starts the game;
it prints an initial printf but never reaches the loop for the game;

I am required to implement these Functions within my functions.c file :

```
 void display(int grid[][DIM], int size);

 void update_status(int row, int col, int scores[][4], int known[][4]);

 void check_found(int row, int col, struct locations bombs[], int size, bool* found);

 char get_user_char();

 void update_known_info(int row, int col, int bomb_info[][DIM], int known[][DIM]);

 void start_game(struct locations *   bombs, int bomb_location_info[][DIM], int size_of_grid, int players_info[][DIM], int no_of_bombs){}
```

I am also required to use this struct and other definitions:

```
#define DIM 4
#define UNKNOWN -1
#define BOMB -2

struct locations {
int x; 
int y; 
bool found;
};
```

As it stands; my main looks like this:

```
    int _of_bombs = 2;

struct locations *   bombs = (struct locations *) malloc(sizeof(struct locations) * 2);


    int bomb_location_info[4][4] = { 1,1,1,0,
                                     1,0,2,1,
                                     1,1,2,0,
                                     0,0,1,1 };

    int known_location_info[4][4] = { UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,
                                      UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,
                                      UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,
                                      UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN,UNKNOWN };


    bombs[0].x = 1;
    bombs[0].y = 1;
    bombs[0].found = false;

    bombs[1].x = 2;
    bombs[1].y = 3;
    bombs[1].found = false;

    int size = 4;

    start_game(bombs, bomb_location_info, size, known_location_info, _of_bombs);
    return 0;

    free(bombs);
```

This is all written to match the specification, apart from start_game which i have tried to implement but failed to do so.

As it stands This is my code for the Functions.c:

```
void display(int known_location_info[][DIM], int size) {

int f = 0;
int g = 0;
for (f = 0; f < size; f++) {
    g = 0;

    for (g = 0; g < size; g++) {


        if (g < size) {

            printf("%d", known_location_info[g][f] );


        }
    }
    printf("\n");

}
 }

void update_known_info(int row, int col, int bomb_info[][DIM], int known[][DIM]) {
known[row][col] = bomb_info[row][col];
 }

void check_found(int row, int col, struct   locations bombs[], int size, bool* found) {

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (bombs[i].x == row) {
        if (bombs[i].y == row) {
            *found = true;
        }
    }
}
}


void  get_user_char(int* a ) {
scanf("%d", a);

}

void start_game(struct locations *   bombs, int bomb_location_info[][DIM], int size_of_grid, int players_info[][DIM], int no_of_bombs) {
 enum game_status { STILL_ALIVE, GAME_OVER };
 enum game_status status = STILL_ALIVE;

printf("Number of moves = 5");
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (status = STILL_ALIVE) {

        int chosenX = 0;
        int chosenY = 0;
        printf("Enter  X coordinate:");
        get_user_char(&chosenX);
        printf("Enter  Y coordinate:");
        get_user_char(&chosenY);

        bool found = false;
        check_found(chosenX, chosenY, bombs , size_of_grid,  found);
        if (found = true) {
            status = GAME_OVER;
        }
        else {
            update_known_info(chosenX, chosenY, bomb_location_info, players_info);
        }

    }
}

}
```

I expect it to enter the loop of game_start and prompt me to enter co-ordinates however instead, it simply displays the number of guesses and then does nothing else

I Would not be suprised if i have a huge amount of issues in the code, any help would be appreciated, but mainly any help with explaining why it never reaches the loop would help!

Comment: try debugging it's the perfect time to do so!

Comment: Well, you should debug, but to get you started, your statement `if (status = STILL_ALIVE)` sets the value 0 to `status` and returns 0. The statements inside the `if` condition are never executed.

Comment: @zerocool I am unfamiliar with the Debugging process of C, I will try. But thanks for pointing out the If statement issue!

Comment: Try debugging using gdb. It is a free tool for debugging C programs. Just compile your program with a -g flag. You can read about gdb from https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
if (status = STILL_ALIVE)
```

which sets `status` to `STILL_ALIVE` which is zero, so it never enters the loop.
try

```
if (status == STILL_ALIVE)
```

instead.